# Laravel Model, Correct neat way of doing this

Tags: php, laravel

I have this table called blocked users, It is laid out like so.

```
id, user_id, blocked_user_id, reason, created_at, updated_at
```

Now I have a message controller which 2 people can converse. I wish to check if the user is blocked before sending a message which I have done like so.

```
    $blkchk = $thread->participants()->withTrashed()->get();
    foreach ($blkchk as $usr) {
      $usrs[] = $usr->user_id;
    }
    $block = BlockedUsers::where('user_id',$usrs[0] )->where('blocked_user_id', $usrs[1])->first();
    $block2 = BlockedUsers::where('user_id',$usrs[1])->where('blocked_user_id', $usrs[0])->first();
    if (!empty($block) || !empty($block2)) {
      return response()->view('errors.403', ['error' => 'One of the users in this conversation is blocked.'], 404);
    }
```

This is pretty messy but blkchk is getting both user ids in the conversation. setting them as an array which i then target each one individually, It works perfect, However I believe this to be verry messy.

Just wondering how the correct and neatest way would be about doing this.

Comment: If this is working code, you should be asking this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you want to check whether specific entries exist in the `blocked_users` table, you can use `whereIn()` method likewise:

```
$blockedUsers = BlockedUsers::whereRaw(
                   'user_id = ? AND blocked_user_id = ?', [$usrs[0], $usrs[1]]
                )
               ->orWhereRaw(
                   'user_id = ? AND blocked_user_id = ?', [$usrs[1], $usrs[0]]
               );

if ($blockedUsers->count()) {
    return 'Some of the users are blocked';
}
```

Personally, I don't think your database design is the best way to go about it, but this will work for what you need.

Comment: the difference is user_id is the user who has blocked a user and blocked_user_id is the user that has been blocked. would the above be correct in this case or would it just search the entire table for 1 id. because both ids need to be matched or reversed

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood it the first time. I've edited my answer now to suit your needs. You'd want to opt for `whereRaw()` so you can do it all as one query.

Comment: actually it seems the binding is not working %s, if i use the variable it does however i do not want this to be unsafe.. would you know how i can get the binding to work?

Comment: It was late and I've put %s instead of question mark. I've edited the answer so you're good to go.

Comment: Thanks so much, I tried with the ? however I had it layed out wrong. I had the following $blockedUsers = BlockedUsers::whereRaw("(user_id = ? AND blocked_user_id = ? OR user_id = ? AND blocked_user_id = ?), [$usrs[0], $usrs[1],$usrs[1],$usrs[0]]"); Yours works perfectly!